# Visual Studio doesn't use saved Style Preferences

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide

I have created my stylus preferences as shown in the [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYwEm.png)

But when I go to click the button to format the code it formats it for me like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vu8r3.png)

Anyone know the reason?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you have time to check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

As for how to modify whether the c# brackets wrap or not, you could modify the result you want in `Tools`->`Options`->`C#`->`Code Style`->`Formationg`->`new lines`.

[image]

> By the way, what software are you using. Did your modification have any impact on your expectations?